# Sending dynamic form parameters to WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api

I'm using WebApi 1 ( Visual Studio: 2010 )

There are rare scenarios where a client can send variable ( dynamic) number of parameters to a method. (via  `POST` verb)

I've been trying to test it by sending variable number of arguments :

```
POST http://.../api/Claims HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 13

a=1&b=2&c=4
```

On the **server** side :

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic NewClaim1([FromBody]  dynamic al)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, (object)al);
}
```

But I get an empty object on response. ( `200 OK`)

**Attempt #2**

I've also tried with `([FromBody]  object al)`

**Attempt #3**

I've also tried with `(object[] al)`

**Attempt #4**

```
  public class A //using a class holder
    {
        public object[] obj { get; set; }
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public dynamic NewClaim1([FromBody]  A al)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, al);
    }
```

But without success

**Question:**

How can I send dynamic post parameters to the method where I could retrieve those values.

NB :

- I don't want to create class holders  for each combination...
- I don't want to send JSON. I'm talking about pure `post`  `x-www-form-urlencoded`
- I already know that webapi doesn't support nativly with multiple `[FromBody]` parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve form values using a [FormDataCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.formdatacollection(v=vs.118).aspx).

```
public void PostForm(FormDataCollection formdata)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> formEntry in formdata)
    {
        string key = formEntry.Key;
        string value = formEntry.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've just made me wanting to learn the whole `System.Net.Http` namespace :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @jon may help in the case of one level `key: value` object, and in a sole case where all properties are of type string. Otherwise, the implementation to extract a complex object must be more complicated than that. 
I suggest using `JObject` as a type of deserialization i.e. provided by Newtonsoft